# Which nation has the most men's wins in a single Alpine Skiing World Cup season?

Tags: records, skiing

When looking at the men's winners in the [2016 Alpine Skiing World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Alpine_Skiing_World_Cup), there are 17 wins for Norwegian skiers. Is this already a record for most wins for a nation, or the skiers from another country achieved more wins for a season?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Alpine_Skiing_World_Cup) season - Austrian team with 26 wins.
- [2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_Alpine_Skiing_World_Cup) season - Austrian team with 24 wins.
- [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Alpine_Skiing_World_Cup) season - Norwegian team with 19 wins.
- [2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2005_Alpine_Skiing_World_Cup) season - Austrian team with 19 wins.

I couldn't find official statistic, but I've manually checked all the possible seasons starting 1970.

Answer (score 2):

Norway hits 19 wins this morning (March 12th, 2016) in Kvitfjell (Nor). It's now the new standard. And the season isn't over yet !! Heia Norge !!

Comment: I'm sorry @user11000, but it seems I was wrong with my previous search. So I needed to change it. It's really hard, cause I cannot find official records. Anyway if you think something is wrong, please correct me.